# A question about order and prime. (group)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group and let $a\in G$ have order $pk$ for some prime $p$, where $1\le k$.

Prove that if there is $x \in G $ with $x^p=a$, then the order of $x$ is $p^2k$.

My attempt:

If $m$ is the order of $x$, then $m\;|\;p^2k$, which means there is an integer  $1\le n$ such that $mn=p^2k$.

Then neither $n\;|\;p$ nor $n\;|\;k$.

If I want to prove that $n=1$, what should I do next?

Thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$pk$ divides the order of $x$ which divides $p^2k$.Since the order of $x$ is $>pk$, it should be $p^2k$ by the fund. theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: Do you mean to use fundamental theorem of arithmetic to $k$? So $k=p_1\dots p_n$. But I have no idea why oder of x must be $p^2k$

Comment: Apply it to the order $s$  of $x$. That number $s$ divides $p^2k$ and is divided by $pk$. So $s$ is equal to $pk$ times a product if some primes dividing $p^2k/pk$. The only extra prime dividing $p^2k$ is $p$. So $s=p*pk$.

Comment: How do we know that $pk$ divides $o(x)$?

Comment: That is because the subgroup generated by $a$ is indide the subgroup generated by $x$ and by Lsgrange's theorem.

Comment: @JCAA Ah I see, thank you.

Comment: By JCAA. Since $a^m=(x^p)^m$, $a^m \in \langle x \rangle$ for all $m\in \Bbb Z$, which implies $\langle a \rangle \le \langle x \rangle$.

Let $s$ be the order of $x$, then by Lagrange's Theorem, $|\langle a \rangle|=pk \;|\;s$.

By fundamental theorem of arithmetic, $s=p_1\dots p_n$.

There is $n\in \Bbb Z$ such that $npk=s=p_1\dots p_n$. 

Since $m\;|\;p^2k$, there is $m\in \Bbb Z$ such that $ms=mnpk=p^2k$.

Hence $mn=p$ and $m=1$, $n=p$.

Comment: It looks like it do not need to apply the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: I do not understand what you wrote but look again.

Comment: Since we know that $pk\;|\;s$, $\exists n\in \Bbb Z$ such that $npk=s$. $x^{p^2k}=1$ implies that $m\;|\;p^2k$, so $\exists m\in \Bbb Z$ such that $ms=p^2k$. Hence $mnpk=p^2k$ implies $mn=p$ i.e. $m\;|\;p$ and $n\;|\;p$. But $m=p$, $n=1$ will lead a contradiction, so $m=1$, $n=p$, proves that $s=p^2k$. Do I miss something?

Comment: And the use of the fund theorem is easier. Moreover the theorem (uniqueness) is proved in a  similar  way.  Any use of the theorem can be avoided in principle. It is not clear what is the point of doing it.

Comment: If I apply the fundamental theorem of arithmetic to $s$, then $s$ must be $pkp_1\dots p_n$ since $pk\; | \; s$. Because $s\;|\;p^2k$, $p_1\dots p_n$ should be $p$. Because of the uniqueness of prime factorization, $s=p^2k$.